# List of sites is sorted weirdly on the leagues page

Tags: bug, reputation-leagues

There's a [reputation leagues page here](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/year/) and the listbox with sites is sorted by site creation date, I suppose, and it looks kinda like this:

[image]

Not very easy to alphabetically find a site you're looking for when it's sorted like that :p